# Adding a documentation reference for a custom Object attribute

Tags: python, add-on, documentation

It is possible to assign custom documentation webpages for operators by using a manual map:

```
def my_addon_docs():
    map = (
        ("bpy.ops.myaddon.bone_preset_*",            "/workflowpresets/"), # <== works
        # ...
    )  
    return "https://some.website", map

bpy.utils.register_manual_map(my_addon_docs)
```

I have seen that i can also RMB on object properties and then call the "Online Manual" entry. However i can not see how i have to do the mapping from a custom object attribute to the webpage. I tried this:

```
def my_addon_docs():
    map = (
        ("bpy.data.*.RigProps.rig_use_bind_pose",    "/posing/"), # <== breaks
    )  
    return "https://some.website", map

bpy.utils.register_manual_map(my_addon_docs)
```

But then i get an error when i try to call the online manual:

```
AttributeError: 'RNA_Types' object has no attribute 'RigProps'
```

Answer (score 4):

`bpy.data.*`  has attributes like `objects`, `meshes`, `speakers`, `cameras` etc.  None of these collections have a `RigProps` pointer property.  Use the type that the custom property has been registered on.

Patterns must be all lowercase since [this commit](https://github.com/blender/blender/commit/56fc812d1eb41414bf40f856624b84c0af937da7).

Small example, `Object` has an `IntProperty` named "example" registered.  Added UI in object properties name panel to test.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty
bpy.types.Object.example = IntProperty()

def draw(self, context):
    self.layout.prop(context.object, "example")
    
def my_addon_docs():
    map = (
        ("bpy.types.object.example",    "/posing/"),
    )  
    return "https://some.website", map

bpy.types.OBJECT_PT_context_object.append(draw)
bpy.utils.register_manual_map(my_addon_docs)
```

In your case, I'd suggest using the map

```
    map = (
        ("bpy.types.object.rigprops.*",    "/posing/"),
    )  
    return "https://some.website", map
```

Or if you have anchors (or query strings)

```
def my_addon_docs():
    props = ("use_xxx", "use_yyy", "use_zzz")
    map = [
        ("bpy.types.object.rigprops.%s" % prop,    
          "#%s" % prop) for prop in props]
    return "https://some.website/posing", map
```