# How to document a PointerProperty prop?

Tags: python

I can't find any documentation about how to put a property of type `PointerProperty` in the `addon_manual_map`

In the following example, you put in the url_manual_mapping all the operators that I want to have access to the documentation with Right Click mouse.

```
   def addon_manual_map():
        url_manual_prefix = "https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/"
        url_manual_mapping = (
            ("bpy.ops.mesh.add_object", "scene_layout/object/types.html"),
        )
        return url_manual_prefix, url_manual_mapping
    
    
    def register():
        bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)
```

Now I can't find anywhere how to document for example this prop:

```
C.scene.my_scene_prop.is_custom_scene
```

Where `is_custom_scene` is a property of type BoolProperty

Registered like this:

```
class MySceneProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    is_custom_scene: bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MySceneProperties)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_scene_prop = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MySceneProperties)
```

I tried to get it with some different strings but to no avail, here are some examples I tried:

```
def addon_manual_map():
    url_manual_prefix = "https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/"
    url_manual_mapping = (
        ("bpy.types.Scene.my_scene_prop.is_custom_scene", "scene_layout/object/types.html"),
        ("bpy.types.scene.my_scene_prop.is_custom_scene", "scene_layout/object/types.html"),
        ("bpy.types.scene.MySceneProperties.is_custom_scene", "scene_layout/object/types.html"),
        ("....etc....", "....etc....."),
            )
    return url_manual_prefix, url_manual_mapping
```

I've also referenced an answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91377/adding-a-documentation-reference-for-a-custom-object-attribute) but haven't been able to apply it to my problem.

Comment: Have you tried all lowercase ? `bpy.type.scene.my_scene_prop.is_custom_scene`

Comment: Yes, as in the example. I also edited the question as I wrote bpy.type instead of bpy.types... (My mistake) Either way it doesn't seem to work